# Why is the CreateServer function handler being called twice?

Tags: node.js

I installed node.js today.  I started with the example "Hello World" server and started hacking on it. Before long, I had this:

```
var http = require('http');
var count = 0;
http.createServer(function handler(req, res) {
    console.log('yeah ' + count++);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('<b>Zoot!</b><br><em>yeah</em>\n');
}).listen(1338, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1338/');
```

When I browse to the port, my console log shows the handler in CreateServer is being called twice - I added the count so I could be sure.  After 2 'browses':

```
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1338/
yeah 0
yeah 1
yeah 2
yeah 3
```

Why is this happening?

EDIT

Tim Cooper is right.

I changed the logging line to

```
console.log('yeah ' + req.url +' '+ count++);
```

and got this result

```
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1338/
yeah / 0
yeah /favicon.ico 1
yeah / 2
yeah /favicon.ico 3
```

Comment: You browser is likely requesting `/favicon.ico` from the server as well as the HTML page.

Comment: ok, I'll start looking for that.  Thanks!

More To Come.

Comment: ok, that was easy enough. Thanks @TimCooper.  Post your comment as an answer.

Comment: I really like the "mixu" book.  Just sayin'

Answer (score 2):

CreateServer isn't getting called twice.  Your callback is getting called multiple times (once for each http request to the server).

Comment: Good distinction, thanks.  The Community should not dismiss how much small points like this can really help beginners understand.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think I got same "issue". 
I created server.js file in which I created `const server = createServer((req,res) => myCallBack)`. And I returned `server` from that file.
On that exported `server` object in another file I added listener. server.on('request', () => } and I noticed whenever I got some request, my `createServer` in another file was called. I was confused because I expected to create that server for once, and then use it, do not call it again. But problem was that, it wasn't called `createServer`. My callback in `createServer` was called. @jfriend00 Am I right?

Comment: @PredragDavidovic - Sorry, but  I can't really answer without seeing your actual code.  Please write your own question and show your own code.  You can leave me a comment here after you write the question with a link to it and I'll take a look.